# explain uplaoding .RAW data images into the jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, numpy

Greeting I know how to import .raw data images into the jupyter notebook but I don.t seem to understand the logic explanation.. Below is the code give, please explain these line to me in as simple way as possible

```
# Read input RAW file
raw_file = np.fromfile('Sandstones/'+name+'_2d25um_binary.raw', dtype=np.uint8)
im = (raw_file.reshape(1000,1000,1000))
im = im==0;
```

I tried alternate ways but this was the best as well as the preferred. I have run it but I don't seem to understand the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is some variable. Let's say it is name of your file. `np.fromfile` takes in a path, and the datatype it wants to read, and convert it into an array.

so

```
'Sandstones/'+name+'_2d25um_binary.raw'
```

is the path, if the name is file1 then it will be

```
'Sandstones/file1_2d25um_binary.raw'
```

You read this file into a numpy array which is a special data structure as uint8.

In the next line of code, you simply reshape the values you read from the file to a 3D array with the shape

```
1000, 1000, 1000
```

The last line changes the `im` array values. If you notice, `im` is your numpy array, All the values, which are equal to 0 will be changed to 1 as `im==0` will be true, rest will be changed to false. You can think of these as a Boolean array of 0s and 1s where 1 are those number which were 0 in the original array. You can learn more about it [here](https://python-course.eu/numerical-programming/numpy-boolean-indexing.php)

Comment: thank you sir.. please could you tell me an alternate way to replace the last line of code

Comment: You can upvote and tick the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: sir can you please elaborate a little more about why did we did this step. I mean I got the point of this last line being a condition. but please could you tell me why we did this..? was this an inversion operation, does it has to do to anything with the data structure unit8? please do reply

Comment: It can be used as a masking operation. I can not comment on it more without knowing the problem context but this is mostly used to get specific elements out of array. i.e arr[arr!=0] will give all elements from arr that are not 0.

Comment: the scenario is I am uploading .raw data in the form of a binary image into the jupyter notebook in which 0 represents void spaces and 1 represents the solid portion..

Comment: is it because np array reads the data inversely i.e., 0 gives solid and 1 gives void space